# Regression of different but similar groups

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I recently encountered the following problem. Suppose I want to predict y from X with regression analysis.

1. The data is given in groups (for example by country).
2. My assumption is that some groups are very similar and can be learned together but others are very different.
3. I don't have enough data to do regression for each group separately.

Is there a way to learn the coefficients together, encouraging them to be similar but not the same? I thought maybe of embedding but I would like to start with something simple.

Comment: Do you know in advance which groups are likely to be similar? Or is this something that would have to be learned from the data itself?

Comment: I have some intuition but it is very high level. For example I saw that grouping by continent helps prediction on a validation set.

Comment: check group lasso or elastic net literature ...